# How to create my own pipe in asyncio.create_subprocess_exec

Tags: python, subprocess, python-asyncio

I have a program where I have to pull files from over the network (p4 print pulls files from version control server and prints to stdout). Because the network and IO was the biggest bottleneck and I am trying to use asyncio. I tried using the standard asyncio.subprocess.PIPE, but because I have multiple subprocesses I keep getting deadlocks. The solution I want to try is to make a new file and have stdout write to there.

Here are some of the errors I got

Attempt 2: Error "OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor"

```py
async def _subprocess_wrapper(self, path):
    async with self.sem:
        _, write = os.pipe()
        proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
            'p4', 'print', '-q', path,
            stdout=write,
            stderr=write
        )
        status = await proc.wait()
        file = os.fdopen(write, 'r')
        txt  = file.read()
        os.close(write)
        os.close(_)
        return status, txt
```

Attempt 3: Error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'"

```py
async def _subprocess_wrapper(self, path):
    async with self.sem:
        _, write = os.pipe()
        proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
            'p4', 'print', '-q', path,
            stdout=write,
            stderr=write
        )
        status = await proc.wait()
        if status != 0:
            txt = await proc.stderr.read()
        else:
            txt = await proc.stdout.read()
        os.close(write)
        os.close(_)
        return status, txt.decode()
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I strongly recommend to return to the standard asyncio and to try to identify and fix the deadlock. In asyncio all I/O simply must be either non-blocking or managed by the event loop. This loop uses select (or poll) to identify file descriptors (network sockets, pipes) which are ready to read/write and transfers data between these FDs and buffers. The application code for I/O doing `await` interacts with these data buffers, and not with the descriptors. Using a direct pipe I/O like you are trying to do simply does not fit into asyncio.

Comment: The problem you have is reading the pipes in blocking way. See this answer (and question) on how to do this properly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57736190/2538382

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave up on trying use my own pipe and changed my wait() to communicate, as per the docs...

***[wait] can deadlock when using stdout=PIPE or stderr=PIPE and the child process generates so much output that it blocks waiting for the OS pipe buffer to accept more data. Use the communicate() method when using pipes to avoid this condition***

My working code

```py
async def _subprocess_wrapper(self, path):
    async with self.sem:
        proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
            'p4', 'print', '-q', path,
            stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE
        )
        stdout, stderr = await proc.communicate()
        txt = stdout if proc.returncode == 0 else stderr
        return proc.returncode, txt.decode()
```

If anyone knows if there is a better way to make this scale I would appreciate the insight